# Is there any way to determine the end of animation?

Tags: animation, swiftui

**Goal:** To animate an image then fade away to reveal the (parent) View.

**Scenario:** Animated objects for a few seconds then one object fills the View which then fades into the 'main' View.

**Modus Operandi:**  Animated objects are within a container View of its own ZStack layer.  
When the animation ends, the ZStack is essentially hidden.

**Question:** Is there a callback-like procedure, or perhaps an event listener that determines that the animation(s) is/are complete so I can dismiss or hide this particular ZStack Layer?

Comment: use you can determine it in custom way, apple does not have such a function for us.

Comment: Understood.  I can probably work within a UIView's animation paradigm.

Comment: no, you can stay in SwiftUI, maybe if you show and tell your issue in new question, i can help you to read and determine animation finished time, as I said it would be in custom way